# Using ALE with clangd for both linting and autocompletion

Tags: vim, autocomplete, lint, clangd

I'm currently using ALE with clangd as a linter, but I'm running into an issue when I try to use it for autocompletion as well. The linter works fine as long as I set `let g:ale_cpp_clangd_options = "-stdlib=libc++ -std=c++17"` in my .vimrc file. Autocompletion also works fine as long as I don't have any changes to my .vimrc file relating to ALE with clangd (options of the form `ale_cpp_clangd_options =`). However, setting this ALE with clangd option (or, seemingly, any ALE with clangd option) disables autocompletion. I've read the ALE and clangd man pages but, unless I've missed something, there wasn't anything that helped with the issue I'm seeing. Is it possible to use ALE with clangd for both linting and autocompletion? Or do these features just not play well together?

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl, I don't know that it's an issue with ALE, but I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I don't know either, but that's certainly not a programming question.